# How to show object controls outside the canvas using fabricjs2

Tags: jquery, fabricjs2

I want to show object's control outside the canvas. I don't want to clip any object in clipping area. I just show the object control outside the canvas then I can move forward to make another functionality which is depends on it.

Any solution for it?
Check screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You want like [this](http://fabricjs.com/controls)?

Comment: No not like that.

Comment: No everything draws in canvas, can't show controls outside.

Comment: Ok. So I have to find another solution for that fuctionality.